# JavaScript, `this`, and Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm currently trying to come up with a way of formatting my Polymer/Web Component JavaScript so that it is neat and can be unit-tested with Jest.

I have come up with the bulk of a solution; however, the way I have written it destroys the correct binding of 'this' to the created Polymer component. I'm trying to figure out a way to bind 'this' correctly, but it has eluded me so far.

Here's what I have so far:

```
'use strict';

// Register element with Polymer
if (window && window.Polymer) {
  Polymer(someElement());
}

/**
 * Some Element
 */
function someElement() {

  return {
    is: 'some-element',

    properties: {
      /**
       * Some Data
       */
      someData: {
        type: Array,
        notify: true,
        value: [],
      },

      /**
       * Selected Object
       */
      selected: {
        type: Object,
      }
    },

    publicFn1,
    publicFn2,

    _privateFn1
  };

  /* Public API
   * ====================================================== */

  /**
   * Public Function 1
   */
  function publicFn1() {
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Public Function 2
   */
  function publicFn2() {
    return this;
  }

  /* Private API
   * ====================================================== */

  /**
   * Private Function 1
   */
  function _privateFn1() {
    return this;
  }

}

// Export for testing
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
  module.exports = someElement();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the function as a behavior instead? You only have to move out the `is` property to the Polymer factory instead and call the function inside the behaviors list.

Comment: Kinda like `Polymer({is: 'my-el', behaviors: [myFunc.call(this)]})`

Comment: I think you have to bind every function to the object explicitly with `bind` function. `publicFn1` property in the object is a link to the function (not method) and that function will have its own `this`. Here it is `window`.